# Customize Angular-Cli generator for Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli for generate new components, services and directives. When i create component(ng g c), generator make subfolder in src/app. And this is ok. But when i create directive (ng g d) or service (ng g s), generator create files into src/app. After few creations it looks very messy. Is it a way to generate this parts in a specific paths? 
For example src/app/directives/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
ng g directive directives/directiveName
```

It will create directive into src/app/directives

Comment: It works, but you have to create folder. Generator create a folder for every component but not for directives. Could i change generator for that?

Comment: I didn't find any way to do it. On our project, we create directory manually

Comment: Angular-cli create the directory automatically now if it doesn't exist :)

Comment: Yeah, i know that;) I finish few apps in ngX from that time.